# Mock a callback function using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am writing unit test cases in java using Junit. I have a function with call back function.

```
public class RedisCacheServiceImpl implements CacheService {
  public <T> T useCacheElseCompute(String key, Class<T> valueClass, Supplier<T> compute, Long expiryInSeconds) {
    //  .....Body............
  }
}
```

In another class

```
public class NotificationTemplateServiceImpl implements NotificationTemplateService {
public NotificationTemplateDTO getNotificationMessage(NotificationDTO notificationDTO) {
  // .....data....
  NotificationTemplateDTO notificationTemplateDTO = cacheService.useCacheElseCompute(
    templateCacheKey, NotificationTemplateDTO.class,
    () -> notificationTemplateRepository.getNotificationTemplate(notificationType, deliveryType),
    cacheExpiryInSeconds
  );
}
  //.......logic...
```

I am writing unit test cases for getNotificationMessage function but getting `Incompatible equality constraint` issue.
Unit Test:-

```
@Test
void testGetNotificationMessage() {
  Mockito.when(mockCacheService.useCacheElseCompute(
    templateCacheKey,
    NotificationTemplateDTO.class,
    ArgumentMatchers.<Supplier<NotificationTemplateRepository>>any()),
    any(Long.class)
  ).thenReturn(null);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the second argument sets the type variable T to NotificationTemplateDTO but the third argument expects T to be NotificationTemplateRepository

Comment: NotificationTemplateRepository is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
when(mockCacheService.useCacheElseCompute(eq(templateCacheKey),
                eq(NotificationTemplateDTO.class),any(Supplier.class), eq(86400L))).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).